# Magento 2 - Creating collection triggers print_r or var_dump

Tags: magento2, collection

Whenever I call the `create()` method on my custom collection, the page just displays a **print_r** (or a **var_dump**, I don't really know) of the entity that is related to the collection.

Also it looks like the process is exited right after that.

Answer (score 0):

The entity related to the collection is not of type `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity`.

From `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection`, this is the code triggering the `print_r`:

```
/**
 * Set entity to use for attributes
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity $entity
 * @return $this
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function setEntity($entity)
{
    if ($entity instanceof \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity) {
        $this->_entity = $entity;
    } elseif (is_string($entity) || $entity instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Element) {
        $this->_entity = $this->_eavEntityFactory->create()->setType($entity);
    } else {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid entity supplied: %1', print_r($entity, 1)));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You can't have a collection of something that is not an EAV entity.

Comment: could you show us your code, I believe your statement  "You can't have a collection of something that is not an EAV entity." is invalid and that the issue may actually be a wrong class inheritance issue

Comment: Yeah, that is a class inheritance issue because your entity class must inherit `AbstractEntity` and mine inherits `AbstractDb`